# How to get/download the uploaded files form Microsoft team using java sdk with microsoft graph API

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have Microsoft account with some groups and uploaded few documents on it.
I have authentication code to connect to MS team and call the Microsoft graph API in place and it is working fine I can access few of the Teams api like get list of groups. channels and user.

But my requirement is I want to download the uploaded file to any group or channel of the MS teams.

I am trying below API to access it

```
                      graphClient.teams("acebf8ec-ea79-45f5-9570-b8e0bcdeeaba").channels(
                      "19%3afd70e03ba2c24cd7bffac753149dc620%40thread.tacv2").filesFolder().
                      buildRequest().get();  
            
  InputStream stream = graphClient.customRequest("/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content", 
  InputStream.class) .buildRequest() .get();
```

what will be the {item-id} here how we get the id, any API for this?
With help of these API I am unable to get the file uploaded on MS teams.

Please help me.
I am looking for the java code to achieve this.

Thank you!!

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/root/children` gives you the list of driveitems. Each object has `id` which is noting but the itemid. Pick the id which you want to get the content for and use the same call that you said above.

Comment: Do I need to put  InputStream stream = graphClient.customRequest("/groups/{group-id}/drive/root/children", InputStream.class) .buildRequest() .get();  ?

Comment: Not sure about the code, but you can get the list of drive items with that call. You can also test the graph calls in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma is correct. You don't need `InputStream stream = graphClient.customRequest("/groups/{group-id}/drive/root/children", InputStream.class) .buildRequest() .get();`. Just directly use `/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content` after you get the item id.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: Sure @Allen Wu :)-

Comment: @varsha, if my answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking the check mark so that it could be helpful to others.

Comment: It's not working giving me a error ```SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ResourceNotFound
Error message: Invalid version: v1.0groups

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0groups/b9323248-5f55-4639-b96d-43b1181a109e/drive/root/children
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.7.1
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


404 : Not Found
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ResourceNotFound

Comment: Meanwhile I tried to get the content of file by using InputStream stream =  graphClient.customRequest("/drives/{driveId}/items/{item-id}/content", InputStream.class) .buildRequest().get();  it is working and I can the object for stream but now facing to read the stream object in java to get the file. Could you please help me?

Comment: In stream object i am getting value of available as 0 even though we have the content in files looks like I am not getting the content properly.

Comment: If you give me java code snippet to get the file from driveId and store it somewhere will help. Thanks @ShivaKeshavVarma

Comment: @varsha The first error was due to there is no forward slash(/) between v1.0 and groups. For the second issue, this is the Java code for downloading stream data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java. Please upvote and accept it so that it can help others solve their issue :)-

Comment: What I suppose to do when I get the stream object how I can fetch the file. I am not getting any way to get the file.@ShivaKeshavVarma

Answer (score 0):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/root/children`

gives you the list of driveitems. Each object has id which is noting but the itemid. Pick the id which you want to get the content for and use the same call as you said.

`/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content`

You can test your graph API calls in [Graph Explore](https://aka.ms/ge) as well.